# make archive page grid layout with bootstrap

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, archive, grid-layout

I want a page that has all of the archive posts of my food category (category id is 10). I am trying to set it up using col-md-4 so I would have three posts in one row.  I think I added all of the necessary elements to my php file, I just don't know how to set it up now. I tried to set it up so that there is 4 column's of 3 posts (so 12 posts) and then after every 12 posts it would load the ajax load more button. Can anyone help me out in trying to get this to work. Thanks in advance.

UPDATED it's still not looping through the posts correctly - and it is only showing one post

```html
<?php
get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel-food');

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1)
] );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div id="ajax">                                     
<article class="post">    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
        <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
        <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
</article>
 </div>
    <?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
       load_more_button();
    }
}
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a new row in each loop iteration.     You can change your code by putting the row outside the loop:

```
<div class="row">
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();

<article class="post">    

    <div class="col-md-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
        <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
        <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
    </div>
</article>
}
</div>

<?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
   load_more_button();
}
```

Also I think you may want to move your ajax option outside of the loop ?